# Tryiing to force Liquibase to use Postgres mode for H2 in-memory DB

Tags: postgresql, h2, liquibase

I'm using a Postgres database in production, so I want to use H2 in Postgres compatibility mode when running tests to ensure it behaves in a similar way. The problem is that Liquibase seems to assume it will be running in a native mode and so generates H2 style datatypes for its changes.

So, basically, I'm setting up H2 with a JDBC URL like this:

```
jdbc:h2:mem:~/mydb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=TRUE;MVCC=true;
```

But the problem is that Liquibase still generates table create statements using "NUMBER" as a datatype rather than the "NUMERIC" which H2 expects in PostgreSQL mode. If I remove the "MODE=PostgreSQL" from the URL it works fine - but then I'm not getting Postgres behaviour in my unit tests.

So, is there a way to get Liquibase to detect the database as Postgres, or force it to, when using the H2 database?

Comment: So what's the problem? Your Java code needs to be flexible enough to deal with that to begin with. And if it isn't testing against a different DBMS doesn't really make sense anyway. But you can always simply use `numeric` as the data type in your change set

Comment: For a start it means I need two different versions of <insert> tasks in my changelogs because the nextval() syntax is different. It's ugly, and it means I'm basically testing something other than my production code.

Comment: @BarrySW19 Can you include an example of the changeset you are using? I'd like to address the comment below by adding a test to Liquibase.

Answer (score 2):

Liquibase does not currently (3.8.x) have a mechanism for detecting the compatibility mode of an H2 database. You might be able to get Liquibase to do what you want using a combination of preconditions and modifysql instructions in the changelog.

Comment: Actually the `NUMBER` data type should not be generated for H2 regardless of its compatibility mode, but Liquibase uses it instead of Standard-compliant `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL` without any good reason.